# Error SevenZipJBinding in dynamic web project

Tags: java, java-native-interface, 7zip, compression

I'm using sevenZipJBinding to uncompress a  .tar  file in dynamic web project i put their jar in my project and when I run it i get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/sevenzipjbinding/IInStream
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
```

What does it mean ?

And how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the method `invoke` in the class `com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression` uses the class or interface `net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.IInStream` at line 111 of the source file it was compiled from (`TagMethodExpression.java`), but the classloader is unable to find that class now (it's probably missing), even though it was probably present at compile time (unless someone edited the bytecode manually).

I'm not sure if that's what you wanted to know, but it definitely is what you asked for.

Comment: Think you for your answer but i want to know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you any idea about this problem??